# Suppose Division ring D is infinite, Prove D* is not finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose Division ring D is infinite, Prove D* is not finitely generated.
Either prove or disprove
Proven for the field.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

You say that you've proven the result when $D$ is commutative, which shows that your question in full generality is equivalent to the following open conjecture:

> If $D$ is a division ring and $D^\times$ is a finitely generated group, then $D$ is commutative.

By a [result](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-06/S0002-9939-99-05182-5/) of Akbari and Mahdavi-Hezavehi, the conjecture is known to be true in the case that $D$ is finite-dimensional over its center.

Comment: Please review *carefully* the current policy of [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), which now applies to not only askers, but also the answerers that answer very low quality questions.